# Magento is ignoring my changes in html files

Tags: magento

I am trying to update cart page in Magento, and more specifically files from web/template/cart. I copied all these files to my custom theme, but somehow all changes are ignored and Magento still using files from vendor. It only happens to html file - phtml are updating correctly.
Tried to clear cache etc. but without any success.
Any ideas?

Comment: have you changed XML files?
app/design/default/THEMENAME/layout

Answer (score 0):

What file are you editing? Put some example for the name and directory. If the changes not applied so don´t rewritting the files.